# Problem running pyproj installed with pip but not with conda

Tags: pyproj, conda, pip

I am running Python 3.11.4

I would like to use pyproj 3.6 to calculate geoid heights as described in the documentation exemple.
However, I don't get the same result as in the documentation when installing pyproj 3.6.0 with pip.

```
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
python
>>> from pyproj import CRS, Transformer
>>> from pyproj.crs import CompoundCRS
>>> src_crs = CRS("EPSG:4979") # Any 3D CRS, here the 3D WGS 84
>>> vert_crs = CRS("EPSG:5773") # Any vertical CRS, here the EGM96 geoid
>>> dst_crs = CompoundCRS(src_crs.name + vert_crs.name, components=[src_crs.to_2d(), vert_crs])
>>> transformer_3d = Transformer.from_crs(src_crs, dst_crs, always_xy=True)
>>> transformer_3d.transform(8.37909, 47.01987, 1000)
(8.37909, 47.01987, 1000)
```

I checked the result by installing pyproj 3.6.0 with conda and this time I obtained the same result as in the documentation.

```
conda create -n pyproj_env pyproj
conda activate pyproj_env
python
>>> from pyproj import CRS, Transformer
>>> from pyproj.crs import CompoundCRS
>>> src_crs = CRS("EPSG:4979") # Any 3D CRS, here the 3D WGS 84
>>> vert_crs = CRS("EPSG:5773") # Any vertical CRS, here the EGM96 geoid
>>> dst_crs = CompoundCRS(src_crs.name + vert_crs.name, components=[src_crs.to_2d(), vert_crs])
>>> transformer_3d = Transformer.from_crs(src_crs, dst_crs, always_xy=True)
>>> transformer_3d.transform(8.37909, 47.01987, 1000)
(8.37909, 47.01987, 951.7851086745321)
```

Have I missed something, or made a mistake?

---

Thanks to @snowman2, I realized I need to activate the use of network for grids with the wheels on pypi.
If I do it works like a charm.

```
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install pyproj
python
>>> from pyproj import CRS, Transformer
>>> from pyproj.crs import CompoundCRS
>>>
>>> pyproj.network.set_network_enabled(active=True)
>>>
>>> src_crs = CRS("EPSG:4979") # Any 3D CRS, here the 3D WGS 84
>>> vert_crs = CRS("EPSG:5773") # Any vertical CRS, here the EGM96 geoid
>>> dst_crs = CompoundCRS(src_crs.name + vert_crs.name, components=[src_crs.to_2d(), vert_crs])
>>> transformer_3d = Transformer.from_crs(src_crs, dst_crs, always_xy=True)
>>> transformer_3d.transform(8.37909, 47.01987, 1000)
(8.37909, 47.01987, 951.7851086745321)
```

Comment: Couple things I'd check first. Are you sure you installed 3.6.0 on both envs? `conda list` and `pip list`. Check the versions and how their dependences were installed. If you run the same processes twice (on conda or pip), are the answers the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conda has the `PROJ_NETWORK` environment variable enabled by default. This makes it so all of the transformation grids are available. This is not true for the wheels on pypi. If you enable PROJ network for the pip installed version or download the grids, I would imagine that they should behave the same.

For more details: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/transformation_grids.html